# How to get better performance with drawing markers on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have database which have nearly ~30.000 records and sql query which get those records and processsing time to return to geoJSON take ~2sec.

The issue I have got is with drawing those points on map which takes ~5sec which is too long.

That's my code for getting geoJSON, drawing and clustering points:

```
    var map;
    var markerClusterer;

    var options = {
        SUCCESS: {
            icon: '/img/marker/green.png',
            zIndex: 2
        },
        FAIL: {
            icon: '/img/marker/red.png',
            zIndex: 3
        },
        NA: {
            icon: '/img/marker/yellow.png',
            zIndex: 1
        }
    };

    var markerGroups = {
        "SUCCESS": [],
        "FAIL": [],
        "NA": []
    };

    function getJSON(url) {
        var jsPromise = Promise.resolve($.ajax(url));
        return jsPromise.then(JSON.parse);
    }

    function load() {

        var opts = {
            streetViewControl: false,
            tilt: 0,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.879094,-97.381205),
            zoom: 4
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), opts);

        markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map);
        markerClusterer.setMaxZoom(15);

        getJSON('/api/maps/points').then(function (json) {
            var markers = json.features;

            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var properties = markers[i].properties;
                var type = properties.value;
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markers[i].geometry.coordinates[1]),
                    parseFloat(markers[i].geometry.coordinates[0]));
                var marker = createMarker(point, type, map, properties);
            }

            markerClusterer.addMarkers(markerGroups["NA"]);
            markerClusterer.addMarkers(markerGroups["SUCCESS"]);
            markerClusterer.addMarkers(markerGroups["FAIL"]);

        });

    }

    function createMarker(point, type, map, properties) {
        var obj;

        if(!options[type]) obj = options['NA'];
        else obj = options[type];

        var icon = obj.icon;
        var zIndex = obj.zIndex;

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon,
            type: type,
            zIndex: parseInt(zIndex)
        });

        if (!markerGroups[type]){
            markerGroups["NA"].push(marker);
        }  else {
            markerGroups[type].push(marker);
        }

        return marker;
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', load);
```

What's the most efficient way to draw those points? 
Currently it draw all points. It's possible to draw point only for bounding box?

Comment: there are several ways to tackle this.  i went with [MarkerClusterer](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html).  see here for other methods: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?hl=en

Comment: @devlincarnate Currently I'm using MarkerClusterer but it's still too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few tips

change your

```
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
```

avoiding the calculation of lenght every time  this way

```
      mylen= markers.len 
      for (var i = 0; i < mylen; i++) {
```

You can reduce slightly the drawing time simplify the latLng construction using

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-latlng-literal

You can store in your json and pass directly the object avoiding the overhead due to the latLng calculation.

Another strategy is reduce the number of point you render searching only the point inside your map bound. If you have saved the point in db this is easy.

You can also show the point only at a certain zoom...

Comment: Yes, I've got also geoHash with precision 10 stored in db

Comment: You can use map.getBounds(); for obtain (south-west latitude, longitude),(north-east latitude, longitude) and in ajax with this value you can extract the marker you need. format the proper json response and render..